# Pandoc markdown page break

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

Recently I started using Pandoc markdown which seems a good alternative to LaTeX, as my document does not have many mathematical formulas, and I do not have ANY experience with LaTeX, which combined with less than 2 week submission deadline makes it a good solution.

One thing I haven't been able to come around is how to force it to leave rest of the page empty, can anyone help?

Comment: Pandoc-flavored Markdown is also great when using mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

It looks like pandoc markdown uses standard LaTeX tags for this purpose:

`\newpage` and `\pagebreak`

Comment: Both work (thanks!), but what's the difference between the two or are they exactly equivalent?

Comment: newpage ends the current page, whereas pagebreak is more of a friendly request - it may or may not happen. See http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm

Comment: This is because raw latex commands are passed straight through if the output understands latex commands.

Comment: But it gets displayed in markdown... is there a way to do it cleanly ?

Answer (score 43):

**TL;DR**: use `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` together with the Lua filter below (or [here](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/pagebreak)) to get page breaks in many formats. *R Markdown* users won't have to do anything extra, the filter is already [included](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/pagebreaks.html) by default.

---

Pandoc parses all inputs into an internal document format. The internal format has no dedicated way to represent page breaks, but it is still possible to encode the information in other ways. One way is to use raw LaTeX `\newpage`. This works perfectly when outputting LaTeX (or PDF created through LaTeX). However, one will run into problems when targeting different formats like HTML or docx.

A simple solution when targeting other formats is to use a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) which can transform the internal document representation such that it suites our needs. Pandoc 2.0 and later even [allows](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to use the included Lua interpreter to perform this transformation.

Let's assume we are indicating page breaks by putting `\newpage` in a line surrounded like blank lines, like so:

```
lorem ipsum

\newpage

more text
```

The `\newpage` will be parsed as a *RawBlock* containing raw *TeX*. The block will only be included in the output if the target format can contain raw TeX (i.e., LaTeX, Markdown, Org, etc.).

We can use a simple Lua filter to translate this when targeting a different format. The following **works** for **docx**, **LaTeX**, **epub**, and light-weight markup.

```lua
--- Return a block element causing a page break in the given format.
local function newpage(format)
  if format == 'docx' then
    local pagebreak = '<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>'
    return pandoc.RawBlock('openxml', pagebreak)
  elseif format:match 'html.*' then
    return pandoc.RawBlock('html', '<div style=""></div>')
  elseif format:match 'tex$' then
    return pandoc.RawBlock('tex', '\\newpage{}')
  elseif format:match 'epub' then
    local pagebreak = '<p style="page-break-after: always;"> </p>'
    return pandoc.RawBlock('html', pagebreak)
  else
    -- fall back to insert a form feed character
    return pandoc.Para{pandoc.Str '\f'}
  end
end

-- Filter function called on each RawBlock element.
function RawBlock (el)
  -- check that the block is TeX or LaTeX and contains only \newpage or
  -- \pagebreak.
  if el.text:match '\\newpage' then
    -- use format-specific pagebreak marker. FORMAT is set by pandoc to
    -- the targeted output format.
    return newpage(FORMAT)
  end
  -- otherwise, leave the block unchanged
  return nil
end
```

We published an [updated, more featureful version](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/pagebreak). It's available from the official pandoc [lua-filters repository](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters). The *R Markdown* project maintains a fork; it ships with the R package, so the [feature can be used right away](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/pagebreaks.html).
Note: For converting `latex` to `docx` you have to set the from to `latex+raw_tex` for pandoc AST to pass it along [github issue](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/issues/152#issuecomment-757427744)

Comment: This works beautifully to force pagebreaks with `\newpage` in pandoc's MS Word output format. To use this filter, save the code in this answer to e.g. `pagebreak.lua` and invoke pandoc with `--lua-filter=pagebreak.lua`

Answer (score 6):

can't edit LucasSeveryn answer, told queue full, so add some infomation here.

### way 1: +raw_tex

`\newpage` and `\pagebreak` need `raw_tex` extension on.

// with pandoc 2.9.2.1, not work with docx or html output, --verbose says

```
[INFO] Not rendering RawBlock (Format "tex") "\\pagebreak"
[INFO] Not rendering RawBlock (Format "tex") "\\newpage"
```

### way 2: +raw_attribute

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_attribute

````
```{=openxml}
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:br w:type="page"/>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```
````

// also not support in gfm input format.
// this worked for docx output, not work with html output.

### extension NOTICE

this need `+raw_tex` format extension.
which is not support for all markdown variants in pandoc.

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#markdown-variants

```
Note, however, that commonmark and gfm have limited support for extensions.  

Only those listed below (and smart, raw_tex, and hard_line_breaks) will work.  

The extensions can, however, all be individually disabled.

Also, raw_tex only affects gfm output, not input.
```

so `-f markdown` will work, but `-f gfm` not work.

### format extension

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--from

```
Extensions can be individually enabled or disabled by appending 
+EXTENSION or -EXTENSION to the format name.
```

for example

`-t html+raw_tex`: output enable raw_tex

`-f markdown-raw_tex-raw_attribute`: input disable raw_tex and raw_attribute

Answer (score 5):

I observed that this does not work for .doc and .odt formats. A workaround I found was to insert a horizontal line `-----------------` and format the "horizontal line" style to break a page and be invisible, using the text editor (ibre office in my case)

Comment: How would you `format the "horizontal line" style to break a page`?

Comment: I only know about HTML output, which I consequently print to pdf. Chrome has a really nice implementation of CSS interpretation for print. In this case, `hr{opacity:0;page-break-after: always;}` does the job. You can sacrifice other element if you want to use `<hr>` for something else.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the following approach if you are converting file from Markdown to epub format:

```html
<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>
```