# Disable page numbering converting markdown to pdf with pandoc

Tags: latex, pandoc

I am converting a markdown file to pdf using pandoc. How can I suppress page numbers in the pdf file?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I will answer my own question here:

I learned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965490/pandoc-markdown-page-break) that pandoc markdown understands standard latex commands. Take for example the following markdown file called `test.md`:

```
% A pdf file without page numbers created from pandoc markdown
% sieste
% June 2013

\pagenumbering{gobble}

# First header
etc
```

and the command

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

produces the desired pdf without page numbers.

I tried to use `\pagestyle{empty}` at first, but it did not work: If I put it where `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is now, page numbering is only turned off from page 2 on, and the first page is still numbered. And if I put it before the title block, the title in the pdf is messed up.

Comment: For those attempting in Rmarkdown, add `#' \pagenumbering{gobble}` after your preamble.

Comment: or `header-includes: - \pgenumbering{gobble}` in the `YAML`. Remember to indent properly.

Comment: @DaveRGP, you should probably correct your last comment: in "pgenumbering", the "a" missing.

Comment: @Prof.Chaos, thanks for spotting. I would, but my ability to edit comments expires 15min after posting.

Comment: O really? That suxx. O well, let's hope people read our comments, then. :)

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` also works fine!

Comment: Using `pagestyle: empty` in the yaml header in my markdown file also worked for me.

Comment: @nilon This only removes the page number on the first page (for me)

Comment: @John This does not work for me, I still get a page number on the first page.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464904/74612 → "use `-V pagestyle=empty` as parameter for pandoc"