# Pandoc EPUB Page Break

Tags: pandoc, epub

Take the following MWE

```
% My Book 
% J. Doe

Content

\newpage

Content that should be on a new page
```

When I run

```
$ pandoc book.txt -o book.epub
```

I don't get the second content in a separate page. How can I do this with the EPUB format?

Answer (score 2):

`\newpage` is a LaTeX command and only works when generating a PDF with LaTeX.

For ePUB, you either need to start a new chapter (using a `# level 1 header`), or you could try to insert the following:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>
```

Note that there is an [open issue on the pandoc issue tracker about supporting page-breaks across output formats](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1934).

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for me. Can you insert it into the example above?

Comment: it probably depends on which epub reader you use... try googling "epub page break"

Comment: How is that `<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>` added to the document?

Comment: @Frotz just write it as part of the markdown... pandoc supports raw html...

Comment: @mb21 The source is LaTeX, not markdown.

Comment: @Frotz then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131435/214446