# Pandoc Markdown to Docx with Cover Page and TOC in separated pages

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I followed the instructions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131435/510024 and I could manage to create and use a filter to create a new page whenever I want in a conversion from `markdown` to `docx`. With that I could manage to get a 'Cover/Front Page' in the `docx` file. However when using `--toc` option the filter doesn't work. The `newpage` is not respected and the 'TOC' appears right after the document `title` i.e in the same page.

There is a way to convert from `markdown` to `docx` having as result a `docx` document with a 'Cover/Front Page' and the 'TOC' (i.e. the 'TOC' being displayed in a page after the 'Cover/Front Page')

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are (at least) two possible methods: one which requires changes to the input document, and another where one modifies the reference document.

### Adding a page break to the abstract

The abstract is the last element before the table of contents. Ending the abstract with a page break will cause the toc to start on a new page:

```
---
title: MWE
abstract: ' `<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>`{=openxml}'
---
```

Note that the abstract may not be empty, but adding a single [no-break space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), as demonstrated in  above example, is enough.

### Modifying the reference document

Pandoc uses a reference document when creating docx files. It is possible to create a custom reference doc and to modify the TOCHeader style.

Creating a custom reference doc requires the following steps:

1. Create a new docx based on pandoc's default reference file:

   ```
   pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > custom-reference.docx
   ```
2. Open `custom-reference.docx` and modify the styles in it to your liking.
3. Pass the result via the `--reference-doc` option each time when invoking pandoc.

   ```
   pandoc --reference-doc=custom-reference.docx …
   ```

   Alternatively, rename the file to `reference.docx` and place it in pandoc's data directory, so it is chosen as default.

See the [documentation on how to modify a custom style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-or-create-new-styles-in-Word-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563#manual) for details.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, couldn't test this earlier. I tried both options and decided for the second as it is more clean. Cheers!

Comment: If you are following the second approach from tarleb's answer, and you run into an issue with the template file being corrupted. It's a known issue with powershell. Use cmd instead. Here is the reported issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4758