# Mixed Landscape + Portrait pages when generating word document from RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, tex, officer

I'm trying to create a word document from RMarkdown-so far everything has been great except that I have to output a 4 page report, the first page being a portrait, the following 2 pages with ggplots being landscape and the last page with a ggplot in portrait.

I've tried every solution I can think of. I've made 4 pages in a reference docx that have the orientations I need, but that didn't work. I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334272/12306032) using a header.tex file that would contain this:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59529763/12306032) I saw on StackOverflow using a lua filter in pandoc_args.

```
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  word_document:
    pandoc_args:
     '--lua-filter=page-break.lua'
---
```

The solution that would solve my problem would be this argument from the officedown package: https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown

```
<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->

Blah blah blah.

<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->
```

but unfortunately I cannot download it using devtools() off my work RServer where I need it. Is there any way I can use and manipulate some functions in officer (the non-markdown version of officedown) to get a mix of portrait and landscape orientations in my document? For example, the officer package has this function:
https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/blob/master/R/docx_section.R

```
body_end_section_landscape <- function( x, w = 21 / 2.54, h = 29.7 / 2.54 ){
  w = w * 20 * 72
  h = h * 20 * 72
  pgsz_str <- "<w:pgSz w:orient=\"landscape\" w:w=\"%.0f\" w:h=\"%.0f\"/>"
  pgsz_str <- sprintf(pgsz_str, h, w )
  str <- sprintf( "<w:pPr><w:sectPr><w:officersection/>%s</w:sectPr></w:pPr>", pgsz_str)
  str <- paste0( wp_ns_yes, str, "</w:p>")
  as_xml_document(str)
  body_add_xml(x, str = str, pos = "after")
}

#' @export
#' @rdname sections
body_end_section_portrait <- function( x, w = 21 / 2.54, h = 29.7 / 2.54 ){
  w = w * 20 * 72
  h = h * 20 * 72
  pgsz_str <- "<w:pgSz w:orient=\"portrait\" w:w=\"%.0f\" w:h=\"%.0f\"/>"
  pgsz_str <- sprintf(pgsz_str, w, h )
  str <- sprintf( "<w:pPr><w:sectPr><w:officersection/>%s</w:sectPr></w:pPr>", pgsz_str)
  str <- paste0( wp_ns_yes, str, "</w:p>")
  body_add_xml(x, str = str, pos = "after")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to provide a minimal example that's not working... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Hi there I was able to do this yesterday using the [`officedown`](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown) package. Once you install it you can go `File >New File > RMarkdown` and pick `From Template` where you can select `Advanced Word document`. The example they give you in the template shows both portrait and landscape.